# Console-based TicTacToe game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, tic-tac-toe

I created a console-based TicTacToe game in Python. So far, everything works as expected. I decided to keep the class static, because I figured there would be no use for multiple game states at once. Is there anything I can improve on?

```
class TicTacToe:
    """Plays a 2-player TicTacToe Game."""

    __curr_player = False  # simple bool player switch
    __game_matrix = [  # representation of game state
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
    ]

    @classmethod
    def play(cls):
        """Play a single round."""
        while not cls.__game_finished():

            # set current player
            player = 2 if cls.__curr_player else 1

            # get player move
            while 1:
                try:
                    print(f"Player {player}'s turn.")
                    x = int(input("X: "))
                    y = int(input("Y: "))
                    if cls.__is_valid_field(x, y):
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Invalid field.")
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid Input.")

            cls.__update(x, y, player)
            print("Current game state: ")
            cls.__display()

            # change player
            cls.__curr_player = not cls.__curr_player

        print("Game finished: ")
        cls.__display()

        # reset state
        cls.__reset()

    @classmethod
    def __game_finished(cls):
        """Returns True if one player has won or all fields are filled."""
        # all filled?
        if all([value for line in cls.__game_matrix for value in line]):
            return True
        # horizontal win?
        if any(all([x == line[0] and x for x in line]) for line in cls.__game_matrix):
            return True
        # vertical win?
        if any(all([line[column] == cls.__game_matrix[0][column] and line[column] for line in cls.__game_matrix]) for column in range(3)):
            return True
        # diagonal win?
        if (cls.__game_matrix[0][0] == cls.__game_matrix[1][1] == cls.__game_matrix[2][2] != 0) or \
           (cls.__game_matrix[0][2] == cls.__game_matrix[1][1] == cls.__game_matrix[2][0] != 0):
            return True
        return False

    @classmethod
    def __is_valid_field(cls, x, y):
        """Checks if field is already filled or out of range."""
        if x > 3 or x < 1 or y > 3 or y < 1:
            return False
        return not cls.__game_matrix[y - 1][x - 1]

    @classmethod
    def __update(cls, x, y, player):
        """Update game state."""
        cls.__game_matrix[y - 1][x - 1] = player

    @classmethod
    def __display(cls):
        """Displays current game state."""
        for line in cls.__game_matrix:
            print(line)

    @classmethod
    def __reset(cls):
        """Reset game state."""
        cls.__curr_player = False
        cls.__game_matrix = [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
        ]


def main():
    TicTacToe.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Consider representing the matrix not as integers, but as references to players
- Consider representing players as an `Enum`, and putting some string utilities such as symbol text in there
- The standard way of showing this game's grid is as "X" and "O" characters
- Drop the `reset` method, and certainly drop the mandatory call to `reset` at the end of `play`. If you really need a fresh game, make a new instance.
- Convert this from a class of static methods - which might as well be a module with global functions - into an actual class whose instance is meaningful
- Do not use double-underscores the way you are; this is reserved for name mangling - and anyway, there's not much of a point in attempting to make private members in Python. If you insist on private members, use a single underscore.
- You're missing logic to show a stalemate.
- Consider pre-calculating a sequence of line coordinates to simplify your end-condition check code.

Also, this is somewhat dangerous:

```
cls.__game_matrix[1][1] == cls.__game_matrix[2][2] != 0
```

It does do what you intended, which is an implied

```
cls.__game_matrix[1][1] == cls.__game_matrix[2][2] and
cls.__game_matrix[2][2] != 0
```

However, given that `False == 0` in Python, this risks being difficult-to-interpret by programmers that might fear that this evaluates to

```
(cls.__game_matrix[1][1] == cls.__game_matrix[2][2]) is not False
```

even though it doesn't. Better to be explicit.

### Suggested

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional, Tuple, List

N = 3


class Player(Enum):
    ONE = False
    TWO = True

    def __str__(self):
        return 'two' if self.value else 'one'

    @staticmethod
    def symbol(player: Optional['Player']) -> str:
        if player is None:
            return ' '
        return 'X' if player.value else 'O'

    @property
    def other(self) -> 'Player':
        return Player(not self.value)


@dataclass
class Coord:
    x: int
    y: int

    @property
    def is_valid(self) -> bool:
        return 0 <= self.x < N and 0 <= self.y < N

    @classmethod
    def from_stdin(cls) -> 'Coord':
        while True:
            try:
                coord = cls(int(input('X: ')) - 1, int(input('Y: ')) - 1)
                if coord.is_valid:
                    return coord
            except ValueError:
                pass

            print('Invalid input.')


class TicTacToe:
    """Plays a 2-player TicTacToe Game."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.curr_player = Player.ONE
        self.matrix: List[List[Optional[Player]]] = [
            [None]*N for _ in range(N)
        ]
        self.line_coords = self.make_lines()

    @staticmethod
    def make_lines() -> Tuple[List[Coord]]:
        return (
            *(  # Horizontal
                [Coord(x, y) for x in range(N)]
                for y in range(N)
            ),
            *(  # Vertical
                [Coord(x, y) for y in range(N)]
                for x in range(N)
            ),
            # First diag
            [Coord(y, y) for y in range(N)],
            # Second diag
            [Coord(x, N - x - 1) for x in range(N)],
        )

    def play(self):
        """Play a single round."""
        while True:
            print(f"Player {self.curr_player}'s turn.")

            # get player move
            while True:
                coord = Coord.from_stdin()
                if self.matrix[coord.y][coord.x] is None:
                    break
                print('That cell is already taken.')

            self.update(coord)
            print('Current game state:')
            self.display()

            is_finished, winner = self.get_winner()
            if is_finished:
                break

            # change player
            self.curr_player = self.curr_player.other

        winner_text = 'stalemate' if winner is None else f'player {winner} won'
        print(f'Game finished; {winner_text}:')
        self.display()

    def get_winner(self) -> Tuple[bool, Optional[Player]]:
        """Returns whether the game is done, and the winner."""

        for line in self.line_coords:
            first = self.matrix[line[0].y][line[0].x]
            if first is not None:
                others = {
                    self.matrix[coord.y][coord.x] for coord in line[1:]
                }
                if others == {first}:
                    return True, first

        return all(
            all(cell is not None for cell in line) for line in self.matrix
        ), None

    def update(self, coord: Coord):
        """Update game state."""
        self.matrix[coord.y][coord.x] = self.curr_player

    def display(self):
        """Displays current game state."""
        for line in self.matrix:
            print(' '.join(Player.symbol(cell) for cell in line))


def main():
    TicTacToe().play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. When i started the game, i found it pretty confusing as to what what coordinates should we input. I added an instructions method:

```py
    @classmethod
    def __instructions(cls):
        print(
            'Welcome to TicTacToe\n'
            'Here is the board:\n'
            )
        cls.__display()
        print(
            'The coordinates start at top left\n'
            '(1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1)\n'
            '(1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 2)\n'
            '(1, 3) (2, 3)  (3, 3)\n'
            )
```

2. I found having 0, 1, 2 on the board is pretty confusing. I replaced empty cells with a symbol, in this case -

```py
    @classmethod
    def __display(cls):
        """Displays current game state."""
        for line in cls.__game_matrix:
            symbols = []
            for elem in line:
                if elem == 0:
                    symbols.append('-')
                else:
                    symbols.append(str(elem))
            print(' '.join(symbols))
```

3. I rearraged private methods before
4. I added a win annoncement to know who won:

`print("Game finished: Player {} won!".format(player))`

5. If you used a normal class you would not have needed

```py
@classmethod
def __game_finished(cls):
```

but would have used the normal

```py
def __game_finished(self):
```

less writing

---

Here is my code:

```py
class TicTacToe:
    """Plays a 2-player TicTacToe Game."""

    __curr_player = False  # simple bool player switch
    __game_matrix = [  # representation of game state
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
    ]

    @classmethod
    def __game_finished(cls):
        """Returns True if one player has won or all fields are filled."""
        # all filled?
        if all([value for line in cls.__game_matrix for value in line]):
            return True
        # horizontal win?
        if any(all([x == line[0] and x for x in line]) for line in cls.__game_matrix):
            return True
        # vertical win?
        if any(all([line[column] == cls.__game_matrix[0][column] and line[column] for line in cls.__game_matrix]) for column in range(3)):
            return True
        # diagonal win?
        if (cls.__game_matrix[0][0] == cls.__game_matrix[1][1] == cls.__game_matrix[2][2] != 0) or \
           (cls.__game_matrix[0][2] == cls.__game_matrix[1][1] == cls.__game_matrix[2][0] != 0):
            return True
        return False

    @classmethod
    def __is_valid_field(cls, x, y):
        """Checks if field is already filled or out of range."""
        if x > 3 or x < 1 or y > 3 or y < 1:
            return False
        return not cls.__game_matrix[y - 1][x - 1]

    @classmethod
    def __update(cls, x, y, player):
        """Update game state."""
        cls.__game_matrix[y - 1][x - 1] = player

    @classmethod
    def __display(cls):
        """Displays current game state."""
        for line in cls.__game_matrix:
            symbols = []
            for elem in line:
                if elem == 0:
                    symbols.append('-')
                else:
                    symbols.append(str(elem))
            print(' '.join(symbols))

    @classmethod
    def __reset(cls):
        """Reset game state."""
        cls.__curr_player = False
        cls.__game_matrix = [
            ['-', '-', '-'],
            ['-', '-', '-'],
            ['-', '-', '-'],
        ]

    @classmethod
    def __instructions(cls):
        print(
            'Welcome to TicTacToe\n'
            'Here is the board:\n'
            )
        cls.__display()
        print(
            'The coordinates start at top left\n'
            '(1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1)\n'
            '(1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 2)\n'
            '(1, 3) (2, 3)  (3, 3)\n'
            )

    @classmethod
    def play(cls):
        cls.__instructions()
        """Play a single round."""
        while not cls.__game_finished():

            # set current player
            player = 2 if cls.__curr_player else 1

            # get player move
            while 1:
                try:
                    print(f"Player {player}'s turn.")
                    x = int(input("X: "))
                    y = int(input("Y: "))
                    if cls.__is_valid_field(x, y):
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Invalid field.")
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid Input.")

            cls.__update(x, y, player)
            print("Current game state: ")
            cls.__display()

            # change player
            cls.__curr_player = not cls.__curr_player

        print("Game finished: Player {} won!".format(player))
        cls.__display()

        # reset state
        cls.__reset()

    


def main():
    TicTacToe.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code was well commented, broken down, easy to follow and clean!

Comment: What do you mean by a "_normal class_"?

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex. I think he is talking about a "non-all-static" class.

Comment: Yes a normal tictactoe = TicTacToe()

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer The word you're looking for is "non-static", not "normal"

Comment: Indeed; you should follow your own recommendation and convert all of those class methods to instance methods in your suggested code.